# D3 how to change the width and length of SVG

Tags: d3.js

I created a SVG on google map and I want to control on the width and length of the SVG object

The size is ok but the problem that the location of the SVG is not in the right place.

How i can control also on the location of the object ?

I tried to add transform for the

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
```

but then the size didn't work.
When I tried also to add scale and translate to the projection the size also didn't work.
Could you advise me how I can control on the location and the size ?
The idea that the first location of the SVG should be the same location only the size should change but the location should be always the same.
The current issue that when I change the zoom the SVG also change the location

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js?2.8.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<style>
html,body,#map {
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.stations,.stations svg {
    position: absolute;
}

.stations svg {
    width: 60px;
    height: 20px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.stations circle {
    fill: brown;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.background {
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

#states path:hover {
    stroke: white;
}

#state-titels text {
    font-family: "ff-dagny-web-pro-1", "ff-dagny-web-pro-2", sans-serif;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size-adjust: none;
    color: #333333;
    text-transform: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: 0;
    text-align: start;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    direction: ltr;
    text-overflow: clip;
}

#states path {
    fill: #ccc;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Create the Google Map…

        var first = 1;
        var zoom = 2;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#map").node(), {
            zoom : 2,
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(-53.76487, -110.41948),
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
            zoom = map.getZoom();
        });

        var width = 10000, height = 1000, centered;

        var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa();

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var count = 1;

        d3.json("../d3/us-states.json", function(json) {

            var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
                overlay.onAdd = function() {


                var layer = d3.select(this.getPanes().overlayLayer).append("div");

                var width1 = 1000;
                var height1 = 1000;
                var svg = layer.append("svg").attr("width", width1).attr(
                        "height", height1);


                var states = svg.append("g").attr("id",
                        "states");

                states.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter()
                .append("path").attr("d", path)//.attr("transform", "scale(" + (zoom) + ")")//.each(transform)
                .style("opacity", "0.7");

                overlay.draw = function() {
                    if ( zoom == 2)
                states.transition().attr("transform", "scale(" + (zoom / 8 ) + ")").style("stroke-width", 2 / zoom + "px");
                    else if ( zoom == 3)
                         states.transition().attr("transform", "scale(" + (zoom / 6 ) + ")").style("stroke-width", 2 / zoom + "px");
                    else if ( zoom == 4)
                     states.transition().attr("transform", "scale(" + (zoom / 4 ) + ")").style("stroke-width", 2 / zoom + "px");
                    else if ( zoom == 5)
                         states.transition().attr("transform", "scale(" + (zoom / 2 ) + ")").style("stroke-width", 2 / zoom + "px");

                };

            };

            overlay.setMap(map);

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you attach missing us-states.json file?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you are trying to (1) change the size of an dynamically-created SVG document (entire image) on screen, or (2) change the placement of an SVG document in an HTML page, or (3) change the size of a particular generated element within the SVG document, or (4) change the placement of a particular generated element within the SVG document?

Comment: Also, you mention _"when I change the zoom the SVG also change the location"_; I'm not sure what this means, but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10714057/405017 for possibly-related answers.

Comment: us-states.json https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/data/us-states.json

Comment: The idea that I have google map and above the google map i put layer of object of SVG.When I change the size of google I want to change the location and the size of the SVG object.The changes shold be according to the change in the zoom of google

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question, you should be able to control the size of the SVG simply by using CSS. So, with d3, rather than using `attr()` use `style()`:

```
layer.append("svg")
  .style("width", width1 + 'px')
  .style("height", height1 + 'px');
```

Similarily, you'd control the position with `.style("left", ...)` and `.style("top", ...)`, presuming your svg is absolutely positioned.

Comment: When I tried to add the style of left and top it don't affect the SVG object

Comment: In response to the comment above.... Without additional info, it's impossible to know what was the issue, but note that setting CSS "left" and "top" only has the desired/expected effect if the element is absolutely positioned (as is the case in the OP's question). Also, when using absolute positioning, recall that the origin relative to which the absolute positioning is applied depends on the css "position" property of the parent element or its parents.