# exclude SVG element only from zoom or only from pan functionality

Tags: svgpanzoom

I wonder is it possible to exclude SVG element (like circle) only from zoom (scale) functionality and preserve his panning. For example: in map i point my current position with red filled circle. When user zoom, i want that this circle have a constant radius. When user pan - i want circle to pan with all other viewport content.
I found this solution:

[Scale independent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694347/scale-independent-elements)

But it seems that i can't figure out how to use it correctly with svg-pan-zoom library.

Also I wonder for similar task - is it possible to drag and drop some element? Mean just that element to be excluded from pan functionality? I was try some approach like jQuery draggable but with no luck.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few weeks I've some kind of workaround. I use onZoom event handler of ariutta/svg-pan-zoom library and write a simple function like this:

```
 onZoom=function(currZoom){
  document.getElementById("marker").setAttribute("r", 2/currZoom);
}
```

In my case I have a little circle which represent current position. Now, when user zoom, library pass current zoom level as argument, and we divide him to radius and off we go!

Also i found a way to achieve my other question. Drag and drop is possible if we use enablePan / disablePan in corresponding mouse event on desired element. I can't post code example for now, because i still cant clarify how to calculate exact dX/dY to match to current zoom level, but that definitely work.