# How to draw data points in a scatter plot that automatically re-size when the user zooms in and out?

Tags: r, svg, autoresize, scatter-plot, zooming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preserve descendant elements' size while scaling the parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880668/preserve-descendant-elements-size-while-scaling-the-parent-element)

I have a scatter plot (SVG image created with RSVGTipsDevice) with a thousand points and I want to reduce the size of each data point if a user zooms in, so that the separation between data points increases when zoomed in.

Example SVG scatter plot [here](http://tinyurl.com/bnpfk7o).

EDIT : Code used for creating above SVG scatter plot

```
library(scatterplot3d)
library(RSVGTipsDevice)
devSVGTips(file="Test.svg", toolTipMode=1, onefile=FALSE, title="plot")
s3d<-scatterplot3d("x","y","z", xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10), zlim=c(0,10))
k<-c(1:1000)
sapply(k,function(k){setSVGShapeToolTip(title=k)
myHyperLink1<-paste("http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/", k , sep="")
setSVGShapeURL(myHyperLink1, "_blank") 
s3d$points3d(runif(1, 0, 10),runif(1, 0, 10),runif(1, 0, 10), pch=16, cex=1, col="green")})
dev.off()
```

Comment: I don't know.  I think it is going to depend on whether R has any SVG devices that allow setting of zooming and panning http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html .  I would poke through the results of `library(sos); findFn("SVG")` and see how it goes ...

Comment: How is the user 'zooming in'? R doesn't have a zooming graphics device. Are your users viewing it with something else? Some code that generates your example would be handy too...

Comment: @Spacedman : Example SVG image (above) has tool tips and clickable hyperlinks which make web browsers best choice for viewing and zooming in. Code is a bit complicated but the piece related to SVG is added as an EDIT to the question.

Comment: Can you edit again to give us an example we can run? Create a minimal, self-contained example that shows the problem. Not being able to cut and paste code to see what you are seeing will have lost you 90% of the people on here...

Comment: @Spacedman : Edited. Hope, its better now !