# HeighCharts SVG Keep font-size fix

Tags: svg, highcharts, font-size

I will use a chart made by `Heighcharts` as a `svg` file.

However, when the `svg` file is resized (increased or scaled down), **the text in it should not be resized with it**. The text should always keep the size compare to the outside of the `svg`.

So far, I found examples here:

- [Preserve descendant elements' size while scaling the parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880668/preserve-descendant-elements-size-while-scaling-the-parent-element)

But I can't fit the example (the code from Phrogz looks quit interesting) into my own.

I create a [`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/frankmehlhop/8cLhqukz/) to test on it:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

To visually explain, I attach an image with tree charts (sizes) where the text stays the same size:

[image: tree chart sizes with fixed text-size example]

Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it could be the popular issue with `foreignObject` in exported SVG file when using `exporting.allowHTML: true`, but i didn't saw your code. Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/10fan2yq/

When you set the `useHTML: true` on some Highcharts element, `exporting.allowHTML: true`, and also the `formatter` function to define a custom format of your element (e.g which returns values in  element), then there is `foreignObject` created in your SVG file which includes all HTML elements. I note, if you're using the `exporting.allowHTML`, you have to put up with fact that is the **experimental** feature and it is described in documentation:

> allowHTML: BooleanSince 4.1.8
>   Experimental setting to allow HTML inside the chart (added through the useHTML options), directly in the exported image. This allows you to preserve complicated HTML structures like tables or bi-directional text in exported charts.
>
> Disclaimer: The HTML is rendered in a foreignObject tag in the generated SVG. The official export server is based on PhantomJS, which supports this, but other SVG clients, like Batik, does not support it. This also applies to downloaded SVG that you want to open in a desktop client.

Your text isn't looks very complex, so you can try to disable `useHTML` option if it's enabled anywhere in your configuration.

Comment: exporting: {allowHTML: true},
dit not help for my issue.

Comment: As I said before `exporting: {allowHTML: true}` is an experimental feature, so in order to make your chart export correctly you need to remove that line of code and refactor your code so that it will not have any `useHTML` statement.